# How to make a button inside a clickable element?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, dom

Let's say i have a button inside clickable container

```
<div class="container" (click)="onContainerClick()">
  <button (click)="onButtonClick()">Button</button>
</div>
```

When i'm clicking on the button both onContainerClick and onButtonClick are triggered.
Is there any way to trigger only button's click event inside the container.

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mekd2t

Comment: Use `event.stopPropagation`

Answer (score 4):

Capture the event object in your event handler and call the [`stopPropagation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) method.

That will stop it bubbling up to the parent element.

```
<button (click)="onButtonClick(); $event.stopPropagation()">Button</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<button (click)="$event.stopPropagation();onButtonClick()">Button</button>
```

You need to stop the propagation of the event. This should cover it